# How to fix .htaccess issue in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to change .htaccess file.But changes are not reflecting. Laravel home page works properly even if .htaccess file contains errors.

I have gone through the checking of mod_rewrite enable and apache2.conf files.Everything is perfect but unable to find the issue.

gfdghfguf;l;..
hfjffgfgh
lghkjgkjg
jfghkfhjfgh ghggggggggggggb

    
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On
gb gjf  jfhgj jfhg jhfjf g 

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

It have to give 500 internal server error but it works fine.

Comment: What does your vhost look like?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: Are you sure you're using Apache? And if you're using Apache/nginx then requests to static assets (images, JS, CSS) might be handled by ngingx only, which means the `.htaccess` file is ignored in those requests.